# Sequelize function on where

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I using sequelize 5.21.2 on Node 12.

I want to get like this:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `order`
WHERE (substr(`order`.`code`,1,8) >= '20200101'
AND substr(`order`.`code`,1,8) <= '20201230')
```

So I wrote it like this:

```
return Model.order.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'id',
  ],
  where: {
    [sequelize.fn('substr', Model.sequelize.col('code'), 1, 8)]: {
      [Op.gte]: params.start_date,
      [Op.lte]: params.end_date,
    },
  },
});
```

But It returns:

```
SELECT `order`.`id`
FROM `order`
WHERE (`order`.`[object Object]` >= '20200101'
AND `order`.`[object Object]` <= '20201230')
```

I tried

```
[sequelize.literal('STR_TO_DATE(substr(code,1,8),\'%Y %m %d\')'), 'order_date']
[sequelize.literal('STR_TO_DATE(substr(code,1,8),\'%Y %m %d\')')]
[sequelize.fn('substr', Model.sequelize.col('code'), 1, 8)]
```

but they work fine when I `SELECT`, but not `WHERE`.

How do I get the results I want? I couldn't find any relevant information in the official manual.. (https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html#where)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `sequelize.where` and `Op.and` to generate the select statement using a function and not a column. See this page in the Sequelize documentation - [Advanced queries with functions (not just columns)](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#advanced-queries-with-functions--not-just-columns-)

```
const { sequelize, order } = Model;
return order.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'id',
  ],
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [
      sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('substr', sequelize.col('code'), 1, 8), {
        [Op.gte]: params.start_date,
      }),
      sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('substr', sequelize.col('code'), 1, 8), {
        [Op.lte]: params.end_date,
      }),
    ],
  },
});
```

Comment: The first code working nicely! But the second one is occurring syntax error(`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`)...

Comment: @Centell - thanks i will remove that part of the answer. Was pretty sure just the first would work but found some documentation suggesting the second would but... nope. :)